# Why am I getting a Namerror with the levelous source code on Mongrel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've downloaded the project from github and tried to run it on mongrel as is and I get this error:

Simpleton:levelous pawel$ ruby script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:in `requirement': undefined local variable or method`version_requirements' for # (NameError)

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:254:in `activate'

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/config/environment.rb:9

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from /Users/pawel/Ruby/levelous/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from script/server:3

Simpleton:levelous pawel$

I am running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Comment: Doesn't 'requirement' must be named 'require' ?

Comment: are you sure this is a rails2.3.5 project and not a rails3 project

Comment: @Shiv Pretty sure. It's quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your config/environment.rb

after: require File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), 'boot')

```
if Gem::VERSION >= "1.3.6" 
    module Rails
        class GemDependency
            def requirement
                r = super
                (r == Gem::Requirement.default) ? nil : r
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and before:
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

Comment: This didn't work for me...any ideas? I'm also using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5